# How is the flux change related to emf generation in an open circuit across its ends?

Tags: electromagnetism

Electricity and magnetism are intimately related. We all know that change in flux induces emf in a closed circuit. But how is flux change related to induction of emf in an open circuit across its ends.

Answer (score 1):

If the short is small (i.e. a small gap in an otherwise continuous wire loop), this question can be answered by Kirchoff's rules.  You go around the loop, summing the voltages, as you would normally.  This means including battery, capacitor, and resistor voltages, as well as the unknown voltage across the gap.  (Note that in a single-loop circuit, the resistor voltages will automatically be zero, since the short in the wire ensures that no current flows.  However, with multiple loops, it is possible to have current flowing in some places.)  You can then solve for the gap voltage in terms of the other parameters of the problem.